# Correctly sharing a Gradle/IntelliJ Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm having a hard time configuring all these correctly. With Eclipse and Maven, I knew exactly which IDE files needed to be checked in and which must not be, because they're generated by Maven.

But how about IntelliJ I already read through [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067) as well as some Stack overflow posts, but I didn't get the right answer.

**What I want to achieve** is that an "Import from GitHub" within IntelliJ sets up the project and module correctly without any manual config needed by the user - but of course, it should work for users with different JDK paths and versions.

1. How to configure gradle so that it configures the project/modules in IntelliJ correctly?
2. Which files need to be excluded from Version control, because they are generated by gradle? (Like .idea/libraries)
3. Which files need to be included, because they are not generated but are absolutely necessary for the project/module to work straight away?

The files in question seem to be at least:

- .iml
- .name
- .idea/compiler.xml
- .idea/misc.xml
- .idea/modules.xml
- .idea/vcs.xml
- .idea/workspace.xml

I absolutely do want to share .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml as well as .idea/runConfigurations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can configure idea with the [gradle idea plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)
2. There is a third-party plugin for .ignore files for intellij https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore . 
   You can create .ignore files based on templates for your default configuration
3. Files like `gradle.properties`. These files can contain properties like the artifactory/nexus username/password or some other user specific configuration.

**Example .gitignore**

```
# Created by .gitignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### Gradle template
.gradle
build/

# Ignore Gradle GUI config
gradle-app.setting


### Java template
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*


### JetBrains template
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm

*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/
# if you remove the above rule, at least ignore the following:

# User-specific stuff:
# .idea/workspace.xml
# .idea/tasks.xml
# .idea/dictionaries

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
# .idea/dataSources.ids
# .idea/dataSources.xml
# .idea/sqlDataSources.xml
# .idea/dynamic.xml
# .idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
# .idea/gradle.xml
# .idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
# .idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
```

Comment: I'm already using that generator but it's just not yet what I aim for. I don't want to exclude .idea since there are files in it that should be shared; but the "at least ignore the following" doesn't do it either since it's not complete (e.g. what about modules.xml? Should it be shared or can it be generated by gradle's IDEA plugin?)